# How does the relationship between bisequence and bitraverse work in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, applicative

I'm having some trouble "mentally type checking" the relationship between [`bisequence`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Bitraversable.html#v:bisequence) and [`bitraverse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Bitraversable.html#v:bitraverse) in Haskell. Here are their signatures, according to the documentation:

```hs
bisequence :: (Bitraversable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) (f b) -> f (t a b)
bitraverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f c) -> (b -> f d) -> t a b -> f (t c d)
```

Also according to the documentation, the following relationship holds:

```hs
bisequence ≡ bitraverse id id
```

But this relationship doesn't make sense to me:

- The signature of `id` is `a -> a`, so how can it be accepted as the first or second argument to `bitraverse`, which wants e.g. `a -> f c`?
- Even if we overcome the first point, the type of `bitraverse id id` should be `Bitraversable t => t a b -> f (t c d)`, right? But that's not the same as the type of `bisequence`; it is missing an applicative later on the `a` and `b` in the input.

What am I missing? I'm sure these two misunderstandings are related, because they are both about missing applicative layers in the type.

Comment: `bitraverse` has a lot of type variables, and the caller gets to choose what types those variables stand for. In particular, it can be specialized to the type `bitraverse :: (...) => (f x -> f x) -> (f y -> f y) -> t (f x) (f y) -> f (t x y)`. (You can use `a` and `b` instead of `x` and `y` to match the type of `bisquence` more closely, but then it becomes easier to accidentally mentally confuse the `a` and `b` in the original type signature with the `a` and `b` in the specialized signature). Might be helpful to convince yourself of that first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's break down all of the variables.

```
bitraverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f c) -> (b -> f d) -> t a b -> f (t c d)
```

Now we have `id :: x -> x` (I'm using a different variable name here so we don't get confused using the same name to mean two different things). Then when we write `bitraverse id`, we have that `id` must unify with the first argument of `bitraverse`, so

```
a -> f c ~ x -> x
```

(`~` is the unification relation)

Hence, `a ~ x` and `f c ~ x`. Substituting that in gives us

```
bitraverse id :: Applicative f => (b -> f d) -> t (f c) b -> f (t c d)
```

Rinse and repeat for the second `id`, which we'll say has type signature `id :: y -> y`. We want to unify

```
b -> f d ~ y -> y
```

So `b ~ y` and `f d ~ y`, by the same logic. Hence,

```
bitraverse id id :: Applicative f => t (f c) (f d) -> f (t c d)
```

which is

```
bisequence :: Applicative f => t (f a) (f b) -> f (t a b)
```

by another name.

Notably, when we said the argument to `bitraverse` was `a -> f c`, we never said that `a` *wasn't* equal to `f c`. `a` could be literally anything, and in this case we chose it to be equal to `f c` (mandated by unification with the type of `id`).

Comment: Thank you! That last part is what I needed to hear. Restating it in my own words: if you're trying to treat `x -> x` as `a -> f c` when inferring types, then you know that `a` must be the same as `f c`, so you're looking at `Applicative f => f c -> f c` for some `f` and `c`. Those are all that remain to be inferred.